# sql query to capture part of the content from wp_post

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

I have a wp_post table and in a column called 'post_content', data in it is showing following way.

```
<p>This is good </p>
<p>That is bad </p>
<p>I like [this >> that] </p>
<p>You are a doctor </p> 
<p>I am a [dcctor >> doctor] too </p>
```

Is there a way to capture 3rd and 5th sentence that contain the pattern like [xxx >> yyy] and display the result?

My expected outcome from the query (select dosomething(post_content) from wp_table where conditions)

1st line : `I like [this >> that]`

2nd line : `I am a [dcctor >> doctor] too`

```
(without <p> and </p>)
```

I have many line items with the same pattern of post_content..

Can you pleas help how to achieve this with the sql query?

Thank you

Comment: `where column like '%[%>>%]%'` is perhaps good enough?

Comment: that will capture the entire cell data that contains >> 
What I am trying to achive is to capture only that line from the cell.